# How to easily substitute a Base class

Tags: c++, class, oop, abstract-class

I have the following hierarchy of classes

```
class classOne
{
    virtual void abstractMethod() = 0;
};

class classTwo : public classOne
{
};

class classThree : public classTwo
{
};
```

All classOne, classTwo and classThree are abstract classes, and I have another class that is defining the pure virtual methods

```
class classNonAbstract : public classThree
{
    void abstractMethod();

    // Couple of new methods
    void doIt();
    void doItToo();
};
```

And right now I need it differently...I need it like

```
class classNonAbstractOne : public classOne
{
    void abstractMethod();

    // Couple of new methods
    void doIt();
    void doItToo();
};

class classNonAbstractTwo : public classTwo
{
    void abstractMethod();

    // Couple of new methods
    void doIt();
    void doItToo();
};
```

and

```
class classNonAbstractThree : public classThree
{
    void abstractMethod();

    // Couple of new methods
    void doIt();
    void doItToo();
};
```

But all the nonAbstract classes have the same new methods, with the same code...and I would like to avoid copying all the methods and it's code to every nonAbstract class. How could I accomplish that?

Hopefully it's understandable...

Comment: If they are containing the same code, what do you need the specific ClassTwo and ClassOne derivations for?

Comment: ClassOne has couple of virtual methods that are overloaded in ClassTwo and also ClassThree... ClassNonAbstract is just adding definition to the pure virtual methods

Comment: introduce intermediate class with common functionality    or use templates to create generic class (templates are somewhat difficult subject, you will have to read about them if you never use them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<class Base>
struct Concrete : Base {
  void abstractMethod();

  void doIt() {
    // example of accessing inherited members:
    int n = Base::data_member; // or this->data_member
    n = Base::method(); // non-virtual dispatch
    n = this->method(); // virtual dispatch

    // since Base is a template parameter, 'data_member' and 'method' are
    // dependent names and using them unqualified will not properly find
    // them
  }
  void doItToo();
};

typedef Concrete<classOne> classNonAbstractOne; // if desired, for convenience
```

Make sure to give your abstract base classes either a virtual public destructor or make the destructor protected (then it doesn't have to be virtual, but still can be).

Because the template must be parsed with names looked up without yet knowing exactly what *Base* will be, you need to either use `Base::member` or `this->member` to access inherited members.

Answer (score 1):

I usually try to avoid inheritance if possible (except for pure abstract classes which define pure interfaces) because it creates a tight coupling. In many cases composition is the better alternative.

Also, things tend to get messy with complex inheritance structures. It's not easy to say from your description what's the best in this particular case. Just pointing this out as a rule of thumb.

Comment: I'll +1 this. Composition > inheritance. If doIt and doItToo have the same code, then put them in the base class. ABC don't have to be all virtual pure methods - they can be normal methods and member vars too.

Comment: I can't do it, because my pure virtual methods are for network operations and are therefore platform dependant...